# Print all patterns of string of length k

Tags: java, string, coding-style, permutation

I was trying this question http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/ but I did not understand some part of it.I have mentioned some part of my console output which I have printed to debug the program. Here I didnt understanding that after printing 'aaa' when k==0 why the prefix is again aa it should be 'aaa' as it has printed 'aaa'.

console.txt

```
i is0Prefix is New Prefix isa n is2 K is 2
i is0Prefix isa New Prefix isaa n is2 K is 1
i is0Prefix isaa New Prefix isaaa n is2 K is 0
aaa
i is1Prefix isaa New Prefix isaab n is2 K is 0
```

StringPermutation .java

```
class StringPermutation {

// Driver method to test below methods
public static void main(String[] args) {             
    System.out.println("First Test");
    char set1[] = {'a', 'b'};
    int k = 3;
    printAllKLength(set1, k);

    System.out.println("\nSecond Test");
    char set2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    k = 1;
    printAllKLength(set2, k);        
}    

// The method that prints all possible strings of length k.  It is
//  mainly a wrapper over recursive function printAllKLengthRec()
static void printAllKLength(char set[], int k) {
    int n = set.length;        
    printAllKLengthRec(set, "", n, k);
}

// The main recursive method to print all possible strings of length k
static void printAllKLengthRec(char set[], String prefix, int n, int k) {

    // Base case: k is 0, print prefix
    if (k == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }

    // One by one add all characters from set and recursively 
    // call for k equals to k-1
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        // Next character of input added
         //System.out.println("prefix is"+prefix);
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i]; 
        System.out.println("i is"+i+"Prefix is"+prefix+" "+"New Prefix is"+newPrefix+" "+"n is"+n+" "+ "K is "+(k-1));
        printAllKLengthRec(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37732025/edit) your question to include the code that you're having trouble with.  It is probably worth reviewing [at least this part](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the How to Ask help section

Comment: @EricRenouf I have given the link it contains the code but still I am giving it for you only

Answer (score 0):

This is the trickiness of recurssion.  You are executing `n` iterations of the `for` loop for each `prefix`.  By you're delving to the bottom of one before finishing all the rest of the iterations.

Each time through the loop you call `printAllKLengthRec` with the new prefix, and it will attempt to add every letter from `set` to that prefix and keep going until it gets a string that is suitably long, at which point it stops trying to add new letters and will add the next one from `set` until there are no more to try at that level.  Then you'll unwind to the previous level and "finish" that one by using the next letter in `set` and going as deep as you can to build strings as you can.  I'll try to represent the value of `prefix` as a tree below so you can see that when you get all the way to the end of one "leaf" you go back to the branch and try the next value:

```
''
    a
        aa
            aaa
            aab
        ab
            aba
            abb
    b
        ba
            baa
            bab
        bb
            bba
            bbb
```

so after you print `aaa` you can't go any lower, so you go back to where it was `aa` and pick the next letter from `set` and try that, then keep going back up the tree until you find another thing you can try.

Each level of indentation in the tree is depth of recursion in `printAllKLengthRec`.  We start at 0, then go to 1, then 2, then 3, then 3 again, then back to 2. . . and so forth until we've hit all the cases for this `set` and `k`.  When we go back up a level, we are back where `prefix` was before we did the previous decent though, so we just add a different letter from `set` to `prefix` and starting going down again.

Comment: That's exactly what i Wanted..!! tHANX A lot..!!!! Cant vote up bcz of reputation but one day I will certainly do.. :)